# How to save an image picked from gallery to shared preferences

Tags: android, image, gallery, android-sharedpreferences

I have made an application that has a background image set. Now I want to pick a image from gallery and set it as my application background. This part is done. But I also want that this picked image sets permanently to my application background, because as I reopen my application the default image gets set.

How can I Save the selected image permanently till I try to change it again?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("student", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor spedit = sp.edit();
    v = R.drawable.back;
    spedit.putInt("background", v);
    RelativeLayout bg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.abc);
    bg.setBackgroundResource(v);

    bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, 101);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
        RelativeLayout bg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.abc);
        bg.setBackground(d);
    }
}
```

I want that when the app runs for the first time default background is seen and as i change the background that image should be seen in further launches.

Answer (score 1):

*At below we have assigned our picture address to shared preferences.After that in oncreate section we have checked if the address is valid.According to that we changed the background.*

```
 SharedPreferences sp; 
 @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            bn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            sp = getSharedPreferences("student", MODE_PRIVATE); 
             String savedPicturePath = sp.getString("imagepath","null");
             if(!savedPicturePath.equals("null"){
             bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(savedPicturePath);
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
                RelativeLayout bg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.abc);
                bg.setBackground(d);
            }
            bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                    startActivityForResult(i, 101);

                }
            });


        }

            @Override
                  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,    Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); 
                sp.edit().putString("imagepath",picturePath);
                cursor.close();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
                RelativeLayout bg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.abc);
                bg.setBackground(d);


            }


        }

        }
```

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: rishabh.agarwal.holmes.back, PID: 2532
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{rishabh.agarwal.holmes.back/rishabh.agarwal.holmes.back.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: sorry for late reply.it gives null pointer exception for the shared preferences.so just try again with my edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

When user clicks on the image, in onActivityResult , get the image path and save it in a SharedPreferences . Next time get the saved value and set the background resource to that. Easy. 
Hint: The error you are getting is because you have not declared the SharedPreferences. 
You might declare it like below:
SharedPreferences a = context.getSharedPreferences ("prefstring" , MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: this is not an answer it is a comment on an answer which is already written.